# Delphi 11.3 - New Tools API - manual and example

Tags: api, delphi, ide

Good morning,

The new version of Delphi 11.3 introduces a new Tools API, but I don't see any demo or user manual except the list of interfaces and features.

Would you have more information?

No information in help files

Comment: Has there ever been any documentation for tool api?

Comment: I think the idea is that one should read the source files. They are in the source\ToolsAPI folder under your Delphi installation. (I, too, lack documentation and wish it existed.)

Comment: https://github.com/Embarcadero/OTAPI-Docs

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, in the olden days of Borland there were entries for it in the Online Help. And I distinctly remember a PDF about extending the IDE with the OTAPI. It's on a different computer so I can't give you specifics. And I seem to remember seeing something about it on the Embarcadero homepage, but of that I am not sure.

Answer (score 7):

You can find demos for the new ToolsAPI for the IDE editor on GitHub:

https://github.com/Embarcadero/RADStudio11Demos/tree/main/Object%20Pascal/ToolsAPI/Editor%20Demos

Answer (score 0):

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/ToolsAPI

Alexandria 11.3 online documentation ;)

Embarcedor with this release also provides classes/interface to operate with the code editor

Comment: OP already explains that he can find this. The problem is that it's just a list of interfaces and no actual explanation or documentation.